# Using numpy, is it possible to define a matrix in terms of other matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I would like to do something like this

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
C = np.zeros((2,2))
D = np.array([[A, B], [B.T, C]])
```

To produce a 5x5 ndarray with elements

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 1
4, 5, 6, 2, 2
7, 8, 9, 3, 3
1, 2, 3, 0, 0
1, 2, 3, 0, 0
```

Comment: Check [numpy.bmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html). (name probably referring to block-matrix)

Comment: Also you can simply search "numpy join matrices"

Comment: `numpy.bmat` returns a `matrix` not an `array`. That's more than a subtlety because these behave differently for example when slicing them or under reduce operations.

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's correct. Thanks for mentioning this caveat!. I missed that (because i got more experience with bmat from scipy.sparse)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is using `vstack` and `hstack`:

```
D = np.vstack((np.hstack((A, B)), np.hstack((B.T, C))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can almost get that using `np.r_` which stacks rows and `np.c_` which stacks columns

```
D = np.r_[np.c_[A, B], np.c_[B.T, C]]
```